# How can I selectively change the background colors of previously visited directories in ls output?

Tags: ls

I am trying to selectively change the background color of a directory as a way to label a directory already used. I have used the option:

```
vi .dircolors
dircolors -p> ~ / .dircolors
```

I replace the following line

```
DIR 01; 34 # directory
```

by the next

```
DIR 01; 4; 33; 44 # directory
```

But this command changes the background color of all the directories and I want to change only one.